# Insert special characters in JPA query with set parameter

Tags: java, sql, jpa, postgresql-9.1

Is there a way in JPA 2.0 to set parameter of a query with special characters? I mean, if I do: `query.setParameter(field, "%" + value.toString() + "%");`, it takes % as special (wildcard) character? It seems to me it's not true in this case, beacuse my search doesn't work with truncated words...
Can You help me??

Comment: Please, show your query too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

```
LIKE :feild
```

for

```
query.setParameter(field, "%" + value.toString() + "%");
```

Then value remains free from the '%' sign. You can try to use % in your query and send value from setParameter() method.

You can also try **CreteriaBuilderInterface** of JPA.
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the query. try to use `"\\%"` instead

Answer (score 0):

what ever you pass in as a query parameter that will pass on to query and back to database. So to the choice of escape character of the query parameter will depend on database. Like in mysql it is "\'" for "'" and "\%" for "%" so if I want to send "john's 10% commission" as query parameter to mysql, i will try `query.setParameter(field, "john\\'s 10\\% commission")`; in your case  `query.setParameter(field, "\\%" + value.toString() + "\\%");` should work. But check the documentation of the database to find out escape character for special cases.